# How can I list the Roles the current user belongs to in Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I need to list the Roles that the user currently logged into my ASP.NET web forms site is a member of.

var userManager = new UserManager(new UserStore());

IdentityUserRole[] userRoles = userManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name).Roles.ToArray();

Comment: I can get the GUID of the role that is stored in the DB with userRoles[i].RoleId but not the Role itself.  Is there another method that takes the Id and returns the Role?

Answer (score 1):

```
var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims
                .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                .Select(c => c.Value);
```

Should be something like this on the top of my head

add .ToList() if needed :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that appears to do nothing.